# ScrollMagic with smooth scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollmagic

In [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io), is it possible to do when I scroll my page, then I will get smooth scrolling effect?
I know there is other libraries and plugins that do. but I asking can ScrollMagic can do that? if so, how? I can't find any example for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from my own experience and knowledge of the `ScrollMagic` docs, no, it can't be done.

The whole purpose of `ScrollMagic` is to observe your scrolling actions, and initiate/control animations/other functionality according to it.

Comment: Well, I ask because I wonder how to do scrolling like this website does, http://www.papertelevision.com/index.html#intro. 
I mean, the smooth scrolling effect when one section goes up.. but in scrollmagic

Comment: I haven't found scrollmagic on that website, but the `scrollr` instead.

Comment: right :) but how to do the same effect when scrolling in scrollmagic?